# Why Is InvalidateMeasure While In Arrange Pass Not Working?

Tags: wpf

I have following XAML:

```
   <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:MyControl Background="Blue" AnotherControl="{x:Reference anotherControl}"/>
            <local:MyAnotherControl Background="Red" x:Name="anotherControl"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

The problem is when in MeasureOverride of MyControl I return (100, 20) back. Thought when in ArrangeOverride of MyControl I return the final size I recieve. Therefore the MyControl has ActualWidth the same as Window.

So far so good but while I am inside ArrangeOverride of MyControl and before I return size I invalidate measure of MyAnotherControl.

The end result is the MyAnotherControl is being measured but while in arrange pass and therefore its not notifying StackPanel that MyAnotherControl's desired size has changed. Futhermore as result StackPanel is not displayed properly.

It seems to me I found strange behavior in wpf when invalidating a control while I am in arrange pass. MyAnotherControl is not notifing its parent which is Stackpanel about size changed but it should.

Any solution to this?

If you resize the window it will all be arranged and drawn correctly. Why?

There are two stripes. The blue one and red one. Red shall appear with another height but it doesnt. When you resize the window and force remeasuing it works. Why is this strange behavior happening?

```
public class MyControl : Button
{
    public MyAnotherControl AnotherControl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        return new Size(100, 20);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
        AnotherControl.MyHeight = 50;
        AnotherControl.InvalidateMeasure();
        return arrangeBounds;
    }
}

public class MyAnotherControl : Button
{
    public double MyHeight
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        return new Size(100, this.MyHeight > 0 ? this.MyHeight : 10);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
        return arrangeBounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can override `OnChildDesiredSizeChanged` and not call the base class. This will prevent you from getting rampant `MeasureOverride` calls originating from the `ContextLayoutManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how wpf works. The stackpanel is just enumerating its children and calling their arrange within its arrange. If you call arrange on an element whose measure is invalid, it will be remeasured with the last available size. The onchilddesiredsizechanged of the parent won't be called so the measure of the parent won't be invalidated. You should probably just get the visual parent of the sibling and invalidate its measure.

Comment: I cannot think of any situation that this by design behavior might be of any kind use. Why would they not notify parent about child desiredsizechanged when arrange? Can you think of any usage for this? I am invalidating MyAnotherControl's measure from MyControl's ArrangeOverride method because when in Arrange I know final size which is when in Measure not always the case. In measure the available size might be sometimes infinity and that is not useable value for futher calculation. Though I need the final size of MyControl for layouting of MyAnotherControl. How would you solve this?

Comment: Presumably they don't want you get into an infinite loop where you are constantly invalidating the measure when you're in the arrange but that's a guess. In any case they don't do it so if you really want that then you need to invalidate the measure of the parent element explicitly as I mentioned. Typically controls that care about the eventual size (e.g. elements that virtualize) are not put into containers that measure with infinite extents. That's why you can't put a virtualizing listbox for example into a stackpanel and expect that it can/will virtualize the items.

Comment: I'm not sure what your real scenario is but you should be careful because the parent element may decide (based on how it measures/arranges its children) to arrange MyControl differently because MyArrangeControl now returns a new desired size (based on the last arrange size of MyControl). In this case you're in a vertical stackpanel so you're going to get measured with an infinite height and the height it will arrange you with is your desired height so in actuality you know in this case at what height you will be arranged. Obviously that will differ for different parent types.

Comment: You are right. But to be honest I kinda new this I was just hoping I would be wrong. I guess the only thing that is left is to do it your way.